Solving a multi variable equation - newbie question
I am trying to confirm the correct way to set up a multiple variable equation so we might attempt solving it with multiple linear regression ( or some other method? )
We have a business process that has $7$ different variables in it. We perform multiple runs of the process which produces different results each time.
The first 3 variables $( x_1, x_2, x_3 )$ are an OR statement ( i.e. for each equation we can only have one value of $x_1$ or $x_2$ or $x_3$ , where $x_1$ is 'T', or $x_2$ is a 'G' or $x_3$ is a 'V'
The next 2 variables ( $x_4$ and $x_5$ ) are an or statement as well ( i.e. can only have 'JBN' or 'GXD' as only one of the next 2 first variables at any one time).
The variable $x_6$ can have any numeric value.
The variable $x_7$ can have any numeric value.
The end result Y,  is a numeric value e.g. '$1001$'
We will have 100s of process runs , which then each generate a unique equation :
e.g.
$$A\times x_1 + B\times x_2 + C\times x_3 + D\times x_4 + E\times x_5 + x_6  + x_7    =  Y $$
$$0\times x_1 + 0\times x_2 + 1\times x_3 + 0\times x_4 + 1\times x_5 + 654 + 53.2  = 1001$$
$$0\times x_1 + 1\times x_2 + 0\times x_3 + 1\times x_4 + 0\times x_5 + 102 + 55.0  = 1341$$
$$1\times x_1 + 0\times x_2 + 0\times x_3 + 0\times x_4 + 1\times x_5 + 823 + 43.0  = 1321$$
etc.
I'm not a maths expert, so any assistance would be helpful. Our end result is to create an optimized series of values to reduce the process run time.
Thanks in advance.
